# My app domain does not load on some iPhones on 5G, loads fine otherwise

Tags: vercel, ipv6, ipv4

So I have been stumped on this for weeks now. I have a web app with this link: https://www.discovry.xyz/ and it loads fine on my own phone on wifi but not on 5G data. The error on safari is: "A server with the specified hostname could not be found". When I have been showing other people it has been hit or miss whether the app loads on their phones if the are not on wifi. The back up url: https://scheinberg.xyz/ loads fine under either circumstance. This is a nextjs app hosted on vercel.

I suspect this may be something funny from Ipv6 vs Ipv4, but the fact it loads for one domain and not the other is confounding.

Some troubleshooting steps I tried:

- removing and re-adding DNS credentials
- transferring my domain to vercel from namecheap